# Scala regex match lines with special characters

Tags: regex, scala, special-characters

I have a code segment that reads lines from a file and I want to filter certain lines out. Basically, I want to filter everything out that has not three tabulator-separated columns, where the first column is a number and the other two columns can contain every character except tabulator and newline (Dos & Unix).

I already checked my regex on http://www.regexr.com/ and there it works.

```
scala> val mystr = """123456\thttp://some.url/path/to/resource\t\x03U\x1D\x1F\x04D0B0@\xA0>\xA0<\x86:http://some.url/path/to/resource\x06\x08+\x06\x01\x05\x05\x07\x01\x01\x04C0A0?\n"""
scala> val myreg = "^[0-9]+(\t[^\t\r\n]+){2}(\n|\r\n)$"

scala> mystr.matches(myreg)
res2: Boolean = false
```

What I found out is that the problem is related to special characters. For example a simple example:

```
scala> val tabstr = """123456\t123456"""
scala> val tabreg = "^[0-9]+\t[0-9]+$"
scala> tabstr.matches(tabreg)
res3: Boolean = false

scala> val tabstr = "123456\t123456"
scala> val tabreg = "^[0-9]+\t[0-9]+$"
scala> tabstr.matches(tabreg)
res4: Boolean = true
```

It seems I mustn't use a raw string for my line (see mystr in the first code block). But if I don't use a raw string scala complains about

```
error: invalid escape character
```

So how can I deal with this messy input and still use my regex to filter out some lines?

Comment: Do you basically want your first regex `^[0-9]+(\t[^\t\r\n]+){2}(\n|\r\n)$` to work with all inputs? Note that in a raw string literal, ``\`` is actually a literal, and to match it, you need two literal ``\\`` in your regex.

Comment: Of course I want it to work with all inputs. Thats the idea behind a filter, right? My inputs can contain nearly everything, especially a lot of special characters. So only tab and newline are not allowed in any column. To understand you correctly: To match a \t in a raw string I would need a \\t in my regex?

Comment: Here is a [demo](http://ideone.com/owuWqL) where all your strings are matched. To match a ``\t`` in a raw string, you need to use ``\\t`` in a raw-string-literal regex, and to match a tab, you need just ``\t`` in any regex declaration.

Comment: Would you care to explain your solution a little bit more in detail? Especially your choice of non-capturing groups. Preferably as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using raw string literals. Inside raw string literals, `\` is not used to escape sequences like tab `\t` or newline `\n`, the `\n` in a raw string literal is just 2 characters following each other.

In a regex, to match a literal `\`, you need to use 2 backslashes in a raw-string literal based regex, and 4 backslashes in a regular string.

So, to match all your inputs, you need to use the following regexps:

```
val mystr = """23456\thttp://some.url/path/to/resource\t\x03U\x1D\x1F\x04D0B0@\xA0>\xA0<\x86:http://some.url/path/to/resource\x06\x08+\x06\x01\x05\x05\x07\x01\x01\x04C0A0?\n"""
val myreg = """[0-9]+(?:\\t(?:(?!\\[trn]).)*){2}(?:\\r)?(?:\\n)"""
println(mystr.matches(myreg)) // => true
val tabstr = """123456\t123456"""
println(tabstr.matches("""[0-9]+\\t[0-9]+""")) // => true
val tabstr2 = "123456\t123456"
println(tabstr2.matches("""^[0-9]+(?:\\t|\t)[0-9]+$""")) // => true
```

Non-capturing groups are not of importance here, since you just need to check if a string `matches` (that means, you do not even need a `^` and `$` since the whole input string must match) and you can still use capturing groups. If you later need to extract any matches/capturing groups, non-capturing groups will help you get a "cleaner" output structure, that is it.

The last two regexps are easy enough, `(?:\\t|\t)` matches either a `\`+`t` or a tab. `\t` just matches a tab.

The first one has a tempered greedy token (this is a simplified regex, a better one can be used with unrolling the loop method: [`[0-9]+(?:\\t[^\\]*(?:\\(?![trn])[^\\]*)*){2}(?:\\r)?(?:\\n)`](https://regex101.com/r/wB6eG1/1)).

- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:\\t(?:(?!\\[trn]).)*){2}` - tempered greedy token, 2 occurrences of a literal string `\t` followed by any characters but a newline other than 2-symbol combinations `\t` or `\r` or `\n`.
- `(?:\\r)?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of `\r`
- `(?:\\n)` - one occurrence of a literal combination of `\` and `n`.